# An article before a description

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, zero-article

Should one use an article before a description, as in **You should stick to _ rule "think quality".** or **Look at _ sign "Elderly people"!** ? I guess the same rule used as in "Room 4" or "Table 2", i.e. no article used, but who knows... Either way, actually I think this structure sounds a little bit awkward.

Comment: What research have you done, and why do you distrust it? Simplify the sentences: *look at sign* vs *look at the sign* - which seems correct? See the ngram for one versus the other: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+at+sign%2C+look+at+the+sign&year_start=1800&year_end=2000)

Comment: @Davo The latter, of course. But this simplification doesn't explain why. Could you please give me the rule?

Comment: And I don't trust the ngram in terms of articles: articles can APPEAR before any word in English, although they REFER only to a certain kind of words

Comment: You use *the* because the 'speaker' of the sentence assumes the hearer can identify *which rule* (or *sign*)  you are referring to, and this is easily assumed because the rule or sign  is actually  given in the context. Even when it is not explicitly given (as in *look at the sign*) , the same assumption applies.

Comment: ngrams do not work for explaining things, really. They just show some thing is "out there".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **a** place, with **a** specific rule:
You should stick to **the** rule.

[Did you notice above how I moved from "a rule" there to "the rule"? That's one usage: going from a/an x to the x.]

Therefore, in these sentences: 
 You should stick to _ rule "think quality". or Look at _ sign "Elderly people"!

**You should use the**:
 You should stick to **the rule** "think quality". ///Look at **the sign** "Elderly people"! ?

1) Rule one: If there is only one of a thing in your limited context: Use the

2) If you move from An Apple to the apple on the table, use the.

Question: "There was an apple around here somewhere. Have you seen it?"
Answer: "Yes, I did. I saw the apple. It's on the table over there."

Question: "What do you think of the rule about wearing shoes in the house?" [limited context, only one rule]
Answer: "I like it, I like the rule". [or that rule]